# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ in the domain $1 < |z-2| < 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Expand $f(z) = \cfrac{1}{z(z-1)}$ in a Laurent series valid for $1 < |z-2| < 2$

First of all I wrote the fraction in partial fraction form:

$\cfrac{1}{z(z-1)} = \cfrac{-1}{z} + \cfrac{1}{z-1}$

Then, I tried manipulating the fraction to get (z-2) part:

$\cfrac{-1}{z} = \cfrac{-1}{(z-2)+2} = \cfrac{1}{2}\cfrac{-1}{1+(\cfrac{z-2}{2})}$

Now, $|\cfrac{z-2}{2}| < 1$

Thus, I can apply the series expansion of:

$\cfrac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - ...$, when $|x| < 1$

Thus:

$\cfrac{-1}{z} = \cfrac{-1}{2}[1 - (\cfrac{z-2}{2})^2 + ...]$

$\implies \cfrac{-1}{z} = \cfrac{-1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\cfrac{z-2}{2})^n$

$\cfrac{-1}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\cfrac{(z-2)^n}{2^{n+1}}\tag{1}$

But, how can I manipulate the second fraction?

Thanks

Comment: $(z-1)^{-1}$ is a Laurent series for itself.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{-1}{z} = \frac{1}{-2-(z-2)} = -\frac12\;\; \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{2-z}{2})}$$

$$= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(z-2)^n}{2^{n+1}} $$

$$\frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{1-(2-z)} =\frac{1}{z-2}\;\; \frac{1}{1 - ({2-z})^{-1}}$$

Comment: So, I can write it as:

$\cfrac{1}{z-1} = \cfrac{1}{z-2} \cfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z-2}}$

And then using the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x}$,

$\cfrac{1}{z-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(z-2)^n}$